# Drop rows if some columns have some value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'name': ['bob', 'jake','Sem'], 'F1': [3, 4, np.nan], 'F2': [14, 40, 7], 'F3': 
[np.nan, 1, 55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print (df)

out>>>
   name   F1  F2    F3
0   bob  3.0  14   NaN
1  jake  4.0  40   1.0
2   Sem  NaN   7   NaN
```

I would like to delete all the rows that under at least 2 columns (between F1 F2 and F3) are NaN.
Like:

```
   name   F1  F2    F3
0   bob  3.0  14   NaN
1  jake  4.0  40   1.0
```

This is just an example, but I may have up to many columns (up to F100) and I may want to delete with other values instead of 2 out of 3 columns.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `df.dropna(thresh=2)`?

Comment: So the logic is that none of the rows above would be dropped because none of them have `nan` in two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `subset` and `thresh` parameters of [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.dropna(subset=['F1', 'F2', 'F3'], thresh=2)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'name': ['bob', 'jake', 'Sem', 'Mario'],
     'F1': [3, 4, np.nan, np.nan],
     'F2': [14, 40, 7, 42],
     'F3': [np.nan, 1, 55, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

    name   F1  F2    F3
0    bob  3.0  14   NaN
1   jake  4.0  40   1.0
2    Sem  NaN   7  55.0
3  Mario  NaN  42   NaN

df2 = df.dropna(subset=['F1', 'F2', 'F3'], thresh=2)
print(df2)

   name   F1  F2    F3
0   bob  3.0  14   NaN
1  jake  4.0  40   1.0
2   Sem  NaN   7  55.0
```

Selecting the columns automatically:

```
cols = list(df.filter(regex=r'F\d+'))
df.dropna(subset=cols, thresh=2)
```

##### alternative without `dropna`

Using boolean indexing:

```
m = df.filter(regex=r'F\d+').isna().sum(1)

df2 = df[m.lt(2)]
```

###### values above threshold

drop if at least 2 values ≥ 4:

```
m = df.filter(regex=r'F\d+').gt(4).sum(1)

df2 = df[m.lt(2)]
```

Comment: Perfect! If instead of NaN I wanted to do the same thing but with threshold values how should I do?

Comment: You can use boolean indexing (see update)

Comment: Sorry for my return, if I had an empty space instead of a NaN how would it change?

Comment: Yes, `dropna` only works with NAs, you can however `replace` empty strings with NAs (or use a different method with boolean indexing)

Comment: Thank you, I'm asking this because I'm getting **" invalid literal for int () with base 10: '' "**, do you think it might be for the format?

Comment: If this is for the last approach, it means you have non numerical data

Comment: No, I only have numerical data in those columns